# Dynamic menu background based on div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have a menu like this

```
 Home -- Work -- Pricing -- Contact Us -- About
```

It is using one page layout. I have enabled the Scrollspy on Bootsrap. When I go to a specific div, the active menu background should be dynamic. So when the focus is on About, the background should change to the color as in the image.

Current CSS code is:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      background-color: #080808;
      color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "dynamic"? What do you expect as a result, and what have you tried?

Comment: Image added. Added -"So when the focus is on About, the background should change the background-color value"

Comment: Okay, I can't think of a way to do this using pure CSS, you'll probably need some JS.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr6w7/1/)</kbd>

Using some Javascript & jQuery, we can add listeners to each nav link that change the background of the nav accordingly:

```
$('nav > div.home').click(function () {
    $('nav').css('background', 'blue');
});

$('nav > div.work').click(function () {
    $('nav').css('background', 'red');
});

$('nav > div.pricing').click(function () {
    $('nav').css('background', 'green');
});
```